# How debug Dockerfile which runs on one platform but not another

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run a Docker file https://github.com/yesnault/docker-phabricator It ran fine on my Mac machine.  But when I tried to run it on my ubuntu machine I got an 'unable to attach to MySQL' error.

What are the type of reasons for a Docker file to work in one platform vs another (isn't that exactly what docker is supposed to solve?).  How can I best debug?

Comment: `sudo docker logs [container-id]` would be first step.  Then you can `sudo docker exec` to get "inside" the container and look around.

Comment: Please compare `docker version` between the two systems.